# How can I augment the default metrics in Istio 1.6?

Tags: istio, envoyproxy

As described [here](https://istio.io/blog/2019/monitoring-external-service-traffic/#using-the-augmented-metrics) I am trying to add the `destination_ip` label to the `istio_tcp_connections_closed_total` metric so that I can observe which IPs are being blocked by my mesh.

Since the introduction of Istiod these metrics are exposed directly by Envoy as a [proxy-wasm plugin](https://github.com/istio/proxy/blob/master/extensions/stats/plugin.cc) as described [here](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/telemetry/metrics/).

How can I augment these metrics? Would it require recompiling the plugin at this time?